# get last same kind of record values with primary key

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Hi I am trying to get last same kind of record values with primary key

list.csv

```
tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,1,2
tag2,slate2,flag2,check2,1,2
tag3,slate3,flag3,check3,1,2
tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,3,4
tag3,slate3,flag3,check3,1,2
```

here primary key is col1+col2+col3+col4

and I need to insert new record
`tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,5,6` in this record I need to get last same kind of record[If many record exists I need to get just last same primary key record] [tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,3,4] and fetch and get  3,4 values and make it like below record,

```
tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,5,6,3,4
```

I am trying like, but not getting expected output.

```
awk -F, '!dup[$1,$2,$3,$4]++' list.csv - removing duplicates , but able to fetch expected record


awk -F, '!dup["tag1","slate1","flag1","check1"]++' list.csv
```

I will input "tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,5,6" values and expecting output like

```
tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,5,6,3,4
```

and if "tag4,slate4,flag4,check4,8,9" record not exists then output will be

```
tag4,slate4,flag4,check4,8,9,NILL,NILL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v add='tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,5,6' '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; split(add, arr, ",") }

($1==arr[1] && $2==arr[2] && $3==arr[3] && $4==arr[4]) { append=$5 FS $6 }
END{ print add, (append?append:"NULL,NULL") }' infile
```

Output:

```
tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,5,6,3,4
```

---

Or doing in another way:

```
awk -v add='tag4,slate4,flag4,check4,8,9' '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }

{ key=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4; if(index(add, key)==1) append=$5 FS $6 }
END{ print add, (append?append:"NULL,NULL") }' infile
```

Output:

```
tag4,slate4,flag4,check4,8,9,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: is it possible to delete all records with primary key ['tag1,slate1,flag1,check1'] and keep last matching key 'tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,3,4' and after ['tag1,slate1,flag1,check1']  kind records

Comment: @KSoumya change this `print add, (append?append:"NULL,NULL")` to this `print (append?append:"NULL,NULL")`, if that's not what you want, then open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

**awk**

```
add='tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,5,6'
awk -F ',' -v add="$add" '
BEGIN {
  key = add; sub(/(,[^,]+){2}$/, "", key)
  tupl = ",NIL,NIL"
}
{
  do{
    if (index($0, key FS) == 1)
      tupl = FS $(NF-1) FS $NF
  } while (getline > 0)
  $0 = add tupl
};1
' list.csv
tag1,slate1,flag1,check1,5,6,3,4
```

---

**GNU sed** with extended regex mode turned ON `-E`

```
# helper variables that make it easy to look
# at n process the pattern space in terms of fields
s=,        S="[^$s]"
F=$s$S+   F2="($F){2}"
add='tag1,slate1,flag1,check4,5,6'
sed -Ee "
  1{H;z;x;s/^/$add/;ba;}

  :loop
    \$tend
    N
    :a
    /^(.*)$F2\n\1$F2\$/h
    s/\n.*//
  bloop

  :end
  G;s/\n\$/,NIL,NIL/;t
  g;s/\n.*($F2\$)/\1/
" list.csv
tag1,slate1,flag1,check4,5,6,NIL,NIL
```